# Jupyter Notebook takes forever to launch or requires me to CTRL + C once before loading

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

this is one of the first times I've asked a question here, so excuse me if I don't provide enough information, I'll try to provide any information people require. So, my issue is with Jupyter Notebook/Jupyter Lab, it's a very wierd behavior and I couldn't find anything online. I'm running Jupyter Notebook on WSL2, whenever I run the command "jupyter notebook", I get the following messages:

```
[I 18:05:32.532 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/luhketa
[I 18:05:32.532 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.12 is running at:
[I 18:05:32.532 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=7978516ff4884fa0ca8c562ef18ecf09e4b393da1e42cff0
[I 18:05:32.532 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7978516ff4884fa0ca8c562ef18ecf09e4b393da1e42cff0
[I 18:05:32.532 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

After that, if I try to access localhost:8888, the page will just keep loading forever. I say forever, but that's not true, after several minutes the page will load and I'll get the following messages in the terminal:

```
xdg-open: file '/home/luhketa/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-341-open.html' does not exist
[C 18:18:50.295 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/luhketa/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1123-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=7978516ff4884fa0ca8c562ef18ecf09e4b393da1e42cff0
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7978516ff4884fa0ca8c562ef18ecf09e4b393da1e42cff0
[I 18:18:50.296 NotebookApp] 302 GET / (127.0.0.1) 0.340000ms
[I 18:18:50.306 NotebookApp] 302 GET /tree? (127.0.0.1) 0.430000ms
Parameter format not correct - ""
tcgetpgrp failed: Not a tty
```

The specific html file that xdg-open tries to open changes everytime, but the rest stays the same. After this, the jupyter notebook page will load normally and I can access my files.

I can also skip the several minute waiting period by pressing CTRL + C in the terminal once, in which case the error messages do not appear, and jupyter notebook also works normally after that.

Jupyter Lab is very similar, the behavior is the same, is just the output that differs a little. I've tried installing both in several different ways (conda, pip, apt), but the behavior is always the same. I'm at a lost as to what to do, so any help is appreciated.